# gdb, inverted range, bad breakpoint number

Tags: c++, debugging, gdb

I have several breakpoints set up. They are numbered from 6 to 6.38.

I want to delete a range. Based on [this](https://sourceware.org/gdb/current/onlinedocs/gdb/Delete-Breaks.html#Delete-Breaks) I can do it. However when I

```
(gdb) delete breakpoints 6-6.2
```

I get a following response

```
inverted range
```

When I

```
(gdb) delete breakpoints 6.1-6.2
```

I get

```
warning: bad breakpoint number at or near '6.1-6.2'
```

I googled in many places but I wasn't able to find a proper way to specify ranges. Does anybody know what is the right way to specify ranges?

I would really appreciate any help on this.

Answer (score 0):

In gdb, when a breakpoint has multiple locations, you can't delete just an individual location.  This is a bit of an oddity in the gdb CLI.

This is why `delete 6.1-6.3` doesn't work.  The error message could certainly be better here.

One thing you can do instead is `disable` just the locations you don't want.  Offhand I am not sure if `disable 6.1-6.3` will work -- you might have to type out `disable 6.1`, `disable 6.2`, etc.